# Why does ML training fail on one gpu but run on another?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, nvidia, tensorflow1.15

My machine has 2 GPU's, a GTX 1070 and a GTX 3080.

I have a conda environment with tensorflow 1.15 and all its relevant dependencies (CUDA 10, CuDnn 7.6 ect..).
When calling my tensorflow based training script to train I get

```
#Training on GTX 1070
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1, python train_script.py

#Output
2021-06-24 21:36:24.253225: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
total_loss: 0.010825163 #Trains as usual
```

However when I try to train on my GTX 3080

```
#Training on GTX 3080
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0, python train_script.py

#Output
2021-06-24 21:43:25.828707: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2021-06-24 21:44:15.331037: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "/home/Me/anaconda3/envs/ProjectNet/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1000, 2), b.shape=(2, 512), m=1000, n=512, k=2
     [[node ProjectNet/fc0/MatMul (defined at home/Me/anaconda3/envs/ProjectNet/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
     [[Sum_7/_421]]
  (1) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1000, 2), b.shape=(2, 512), m=1000, n=512, k=2
     [[node ProjectNet/fc0/MatMul (defined at /home/Me/anaconda3/envs/ProjectNet/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
```

Graphics cards info:

```
$ nvidia-smi 


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.27       Driver Version: 465.27       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8     5W / 151W |     11MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:2B:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   49C    P8    36W / 370W |    624MiB / 10001MiB |     27%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Can anyone explain why training fails on the GTX 3080?

Comment: From what I heard, the 3080 does not support CUDA 10, only 11.

Comment: In the nvidia-smi summary you can see it's using CUDA 11.3, not supported by TensorFlow 1.15. When you update the NVIDIA drivers, CUDA version is usually updated, breaking the compatibility with TensorFlow. I now only update the GPU drivers when I install a new TensorFlow version, and use the last ones compatible with the CUDA version indicated by that TF version.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. From my understanding, I thought running tensorflow through an anconda environment with cuda 10 installed was the recommended way to avoid driver issues. If this isn't the case, does that mean I have to install a driver with cuda 10 on my base environment?

Comment: [CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-GemmEx) means the program failed to execute on GPU. This is due to launch failure of the kernel on the GPU. I am assuming you are using `NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080` not `GTX 3080` card. For this GPU card, support starts from `CUDA 11.x`. Once you upgrade Tensorflow to latest i.e `TF2.5` in anaconda environment your issue will be resolved. Thanks!